# Serial execution of a role in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a playbook defined as below:

```
- name: install percona rpms
  hosts: imdp
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
    - role3
    - role4
```

I just want the tasks defined in role 3 to be executed serially. If I define `serial: 1` in the role3 tasks, it doesn't work. All tasks are executed in parallel. But if I defined `serial: 1` in the main yaml (the above yaml) then all the roles are executed serially, which is also not needed.

How can I get just role3 to be executed serially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*serial*" is available in a play only. See [Playbook Keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). The solution is to split the roles among more plays. For example

```yaml
- name: Play 1. install percona rpms
  hosts: imdp
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2

- name: Play 2. install percona rpms
  hosts: imdp
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - role3

- name: Play 3. install percona rpms
  hosts: imdp
  roles:
    - role4
```

Answer (score 3):

[As example (emulation)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70204292/16741045)

my-tasks.yml:

```yaml
---
- include_tasks: custom-tasks.yml
  when: inventory_hostname == item
  with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

custom-tasks.yml:

```yaml
---
- debug:
    var: inventory_hostname
```

Comment: This solution has the added benefit of being able to use it from within a role.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, and exactly same reason, to change a global variable, or to update variables on other hosts, but to run serial upgrades on them and to increment each time a host has been upgraded to keep a counter.  thanks!  hope i can get it to work beacuse this is some deep ansible coding what i have going on now!

Comment: i wasnt able to  get a global variable fact set, using this, and the link included which shows to use a flat file instead.  i dont think you need to emulate just to use the flatfile for memory.  what would be nice is a true way to increment a fact, even if on the localhost only, each serial iteration.