# How to change and use a global variable for each host in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a playbook to setup mysql master-slave replication with multiple slave servers. For each slave server, I need access to a variable called next_id that should be incremented before use for each host. For example, for the first slave server, next_id should be 2 and for the second slave server it should be 3 and so on. What is the way to achieve this in Ansible?

This is the yaml file I use to run my role.

```yaml
    - name: Setup the environment
      hosts: master , slave_hosts
      serial: 1
      roles:
         - setup-master-slave
      vars:
         master_ip_address : "188.66.192.11"
         slave_ip_list :
           - "188.66.192.17"
           - "188.66.192.22"
```

This is the yaml file where I use the variable.

```yaml
    - name: Replace conf file with template
      template:
         src: masterslave.j2
         dest: /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
      when: inventory_hostname != 'master'
      vars:
         - ip_address : "{{ master_ip_address }}"
         - server_id : "{{ next_id  }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a way which will work according to you requirement for any number of slave servers but it is not based on any any module but self conscience.
Here my master_ip_address is 10.x.x.x and input is any value of next_id you want to increment for every slave server

```yaml
    - hosts: master,slave1,slave2,slave3,slave4
      serial: 1
      gather_facts: no
      tasks:
      - shell: echo "{{ input }}" > yes.txt
        delegate_to: localhost
        when: inventory_hostname == '10.x.x.x'
    
      - shell: cat yes.txt
        register: var
        delegate_to: localhost
        when: inventory_hostname != '10.x.x.x'
      - shell: echo "$(({{var.stdout}}+1))"
        register: next_id
        delegate_to: localhost
        when: inventory_hostname != '10.x.x.x'
      - shell: echo "{{ next_id.stdout }}" > yes.txt
        delegate_to: localhost
        when: inventory_hostname != '10.x.x.x'
      - name: Replace conf file with template
        template:
           src: masterslave.j2
           dest: 50-server.cnf
        when: inventory_hostname != '10.x.x.x'
        vars:
           - ip_address : "{{ master_ip_address }}"
           - server_id : "{{ next_id.stdout  }}"

    [ansibleserver@172 test_increment]$ cat masterslave.j2 
           - {{ ip_address }}
           - {{ server_id }}
```

Now, if you run

```
ansible-playbook increment.yml -e 'master_ip_address=10.x.x.x input=1'
```

slave1 server

```
[root@slave1 ~]# cat 50-server.cnf 
       - 10.x.x.x
       - 2
```

slave2 server

```
[root@slave2 ~]# cat 50-server.cnf 
       - 10.x.x.x
       - 3
```

slave3 server

```
[root@slave3 ~]# cat 50-server.cnf 
       - 10.x.x.x
       - 4
```

and so on

Comment: ok so  the only thing i can figure out is also to use a flat file to hold the data.  ive tried everything including emulating serial, update_fact, delegate_facts, looping, delegating to various, nothing still.  It would be great if someone can show how to do this in ansible using facts only, so ansible holds the data, but looks like global variable isnt supported yet

Answer (score 1):

["serial" is available in a playbooks only and not working in roles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475261/16741045)

therefore, for fully automatic generation of server_id for MySQL in Ansible roles, you can use the following:

**roles/my_role/defaults/main.yml**

```yaml
---
cluster_alias: test_cluster
mysql_server_id_config: "settings/mysql/{{ cluster_alias }}/server_id.ini"
```

**roles/my_role/tasks/server-id.yml**

```yaml
---
- name: Ensures '{{ mysql_server_id_config | dirname }}' dir exists
  file:
    path: '{{ mysql_server_id_config | dirname }}'
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0755
  delegate_to: localhost
    
- name: Ensure mysql server id config file exists
  copy:
    content: "0"
    dest: "{{ mysql_server_id_config }}"
    force: no
    owner: root
    mode: '0755'
  delegate_to: localhost
    
- name: server-id
  include_tasks: server-id-tasks.yml
  when: inventory_hostname == item
  with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
  tags:
    - server-id
```

**roles/my_role/tasks/server-id-tasks.yml**

```yaml
# tasks file
---
- name: get last server id
  shell: >
    cat "{{ mysql_server_id_config }}"
  register: _last_mysql_server_id
  check_mode: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  tags:
    - server-id

- name: get new server id
  shell: >
    echo "$(({{_last_mysql_server_id.stdout}}+1))"
  register: _new_mysql_server_id
  check_mode: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  tags:
    - server-id

- name: save new server id
  shell: >
    echo -n "{{ _new_mysql_server_id.stdout }}" > "{{ mysql_server_id_config }}"
  check_mode: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  tags:
    - server-id
    
- debug:
    var: _new_mysql_server_id.stdout
  tags:
    - server-id
    
- name: Replace conf file with template
  template:
    src: server-id.j2
    dest: server-id.cnf
```